# Вопрос по $_SESSION

Tags: php

Я хочу посмотреть, действительно ли при авторизации пользователем присваивается id данной сессии. Я подключил базу данных, подготовил запрос, проверил пароль на правильность и решил через print_r($_SESSION['user_id']) посмотреть id. Моя логика - если id есть, значит он был присвоен.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = htmlspecialchars($row['id']);
#code...
echo "Ваш id: " . print_r($_SESSION['user_id'])
```

Я вроде присваивал id сессии = id пользователя, но было показано, что id = 1, в то время, как в базе данных id у пользователя: 3. Что я сделал не так?

Если я что-то не так обьяснил, то лучше, наверное, показать исходный код:

```
session_start();
include '../db.php';
$login = strip_tags($_POST['login']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT login, password FROM users"); 
$stmt->execute();
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) { /
    $login_in_data = $row['login']; 
    $password_in_data = $row['password'];
    $name_in_data = $row['name'];
}
if ( !isset($login_in_data) ) {
    echo "Не получен логин!"; ?><br><br><?
}
} 
catch (exeption $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
if ( isset($login) && isset($password) ) {
   $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST["password"],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (`login`, `password`) = (:login, :hashed_password)");
$stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);     
$stmt->bindParam(':hashed_password', $hashed_password);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->execute();

if ( (password_verify($password, $hashed_password) )) { 
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = htmlspecialchars($row['id']);

    echo "Вы вошли, как " . $login . " !";?> <br> <?php
    ?> <a href="/personalAccount.php">Личный кабинет</a> <br>
    <?php echo "Ваш id: " . print_r($_SESSION['user_id']) ; 
    $_SESSION['login'] = htmlspecialchars($row['login']); //htmlsp предотвр. XSS атаку
    $_SESSION['username'] = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
} else {
    echo "Вы не вошли!";
}   
}
```

P.S. Если я уж в корне не правильно делаю - то как тогда стоит присвоить id сессии при авторизации пользователем?

Comment: Этот код неправильный не только в корне, но также и в стволе, ветках и листьях и даже дуплах. Как делать правильно: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash

Comment: @Ипатьев вы скинули ссылку о хешировании, а я спрашивал о сессии

Comment: к сессиям этот вопрос не имеет отношения. вообще никакого

Answer (score 0):

Вот стандартный пример кода используя PDO и `password_verify()`. Пароль должен быть сохранён в базе с функцией `password_hash()`.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['email']]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
if ($user && password_verify($_POST['pass'], $user['pass']))
{
    echo "valid!";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```